# Elasticsearch aggregation query now invoking circuit breaker exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of indices that rollover monthly with a few hundred GB of documents. This week simple queries that return no more than 50 small results have begun to fail with circuit breaker exceptions on the aggregation.

The aggregation itself is on a multifield of type keyword. This isn't analysed by default so I don't think it should be hitting any field data limits.

The field this multifield is based on has a custom analyser but I assume that makes no difference.

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "domains": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "top_field.multifield_keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And which is the actual error you get? There are many circuit breakers.

Comment: Indeed, posting the actual exceptions might help in identifying their cause, otherwise its just blind guessing